# Parse HTML in Android

Tags: android, html, parsing

I am trying to parse HTML in android from a webpage, and since the webpage it not well formed, I get `SAXException`.

Is there a way to parse HTML in Android?

Comment: I suspect the Rhino dependency will make htmlunit hell to compile on Android, but you could try...

Also, some other non-strict HTML parser such as soup might work.

Comment: I wonder if webkit can be used here.

Answer (score 76):

I just encountered this problem. I tried a few things, but settled on using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). The jar is about 132k, which is a bit big, but if you download the source and take out some of the methods you will not be using, then it is not as big. 
=> Good thing about it is that it will handle badly formed HTML

Here's a good example from their site.

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

//http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url
//Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```

Comment: You could try including the full jar, and run ProGuard on your app in your production release to strip out unused code.

Comment: CAUTION: JSoup is very very slow.

Comment: @kevin a source for that claim? You may have some debugging enabled.

Comment: What about dynamically loaded content using java script during rendering of the html page on the client side? Will Jsoup show this content as well?

Answer (score 57):

Have you tried using [Html.fromHtml(source)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)?

I think that class is pretty liberal with respect to source quality (it uses [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) internally, which was designed with real-life, bad HTML in mind). It doesn't support all HTML tags though, but it does come with a handler you can implement to react on tags it doesn't understand.

Comment: This is very simple, I cannot search for exact things (like XPATH)

Comment: attention please. this will "Suspending all threads". I face with than when get a json with html format text with in it. there was no problem with showing html text rightly but after use html.fromhtml() I face with this.

Answer (score 25):

```
String tmpHtml = "<html>a whole bunch of html stuff</html>";
String htmlTextStr = Html.fromHtml(tmpHtml).toString();
```

Comment: nice and simple, no plugins, love it! tnxs

Comment: As a note: calling `toString()` on the `Spanned` object returned from `Html.fromHtml(str)` will make many of the `HTML` tags not work (including `<i>` `<u>` `<b>`). So if you're setting a textview just do: `myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str))`

Comment: @Sakiboy You are right. In addition to this there are many other tags that does not work with `Html.fromHtml()`. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3150456/1987045

Comment: awesome , exactly what i wanted , my server side dev was sending me html , now i can easily convert it to raw string thanks

Answer (score 3):

We all know that programming have endless possibilities.There are numbers of solutions available for a single problem so i think all of the above solutions are perfect and may be helpful for someone but for me this one save my day..

So **Code goes like this**

```
  private void getWebsite() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
          Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ssaurel.com/blog").get();
          String title = doc.title();
          Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

          builder.append(title).append("\n");

          for (Element link : links) {
            builder.append("\n").append("Link : ").append(link.attr("href"))
            .append("\n").append("Text : ").append(link.text());
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            result.setText(builder.toString());
          }
        });
      }
    }).start();
  }
```

You just have to call the above function in `onCreate Method` of your `MainActivity`

I hope this one is also helpful for you guys.

Also read the original blog at [Medium](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-parse-html-pages-on-android-with-jsoup-2a9b0da0096f)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use WebView, but as you can see in the doc WebView doesn't support javascript and other stuff like widgets by default.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

I think that you can enable javascript if you need it.

Comment: Yes, you can enable JS, easily. But no need to use webview for html parsing.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question