# Html List tag not working in android textview. What can I do?

Tags: android

Html List tag not working in android TextView. This is my string content:

```
String str="A dressy take on classic gingham in a soft, textured weave of stripes that resembles twill.  Take a closer look at this one.<ul><li>Trim, tailored fit for a bespoke feel</li><li>Medium spread collar, one-button mitered barrel cuffs</li><li>Applied placket with genuine mother-of-pearl buttons</li><li>;Split back yoke, rear side pleats</li><li>Made in the U.S.A. of 100% imported cotton.</li></ul>";
```

I loaded it in a text view like this:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

The output looks like a paragraph. What can I do? Is there any solution for it?

Edit:

```
webview.loadData(str,"text/html","utf-8");
```

Comment: Should be text/html not texl/html.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

As you can see in the [`Html` class source code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/Html.java), [`Html.fromHtml(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) does not support all HTML tags. In this very case, `<ul>` and `<li>` are not supported.

From the source code I have built a list of allowed HTML tags:

- `br`
- `p`
- `div`
- `em`
- `b`
- `strong`
- `cite`
- `dfn`
- `i`
- `big`
- `small`
- `font`
- `blockquote`
- `tt`
- `monospace`
- `a`
- `u`
- `sup`
- `sub`

So you better use `WebView` and its `loadDataWithBaseURL` method. Try something like this:

```
String str="<html><body>A dressy take on classic gingham in a soft, textured weave of stripes that resembles twill.  Take a closer look at this one.<ul><li>Trim, tailored fit for a bespoke feel</li><li>Medium spread collar, one-button mitered barrel cuffs</li><li>Applied placket with genuine mother-of-pearl buttons</li><li>;Split back yoke, rear side pleats</li><li>Made in the U.S.A. of 100% imported cotton.</li></ul></body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, str, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: then what can i do to rectify it?

Comment: very important to note some attributes of this "allowed" tags are not supported too. :=(

Comment: what we have to do for it? do you mean just omit that?

Comment: You just can't use it... it won't get rendered. As BrennaSoft suggested, use `WebView` instead.

Comment: No, you have not said that, at least in this thread. Anyway, can you show us how you are trying to use `WebView` please?

Comment: Oh yeah, I didnt mention the word web view. But i told i used the loadData method. its comes under webview class. Now its clear Right?

Comment: Calm down... I edited my answer, please let me know whether it works.

Comment: You can't actually use a WebView it he same way, so this isn't actually a solution tot eh problem.

Comment: How is that a solution? you can't just use a WebView it's a very expensive widget compared to a TextView. You can't just use a WebView for every formatted text you have.

Answer (score 140):

I was having the same problem, and what I did is overriding the default **TagHandler**. This one worked for me.

```
public class MyTagHandler implements TagHandler {

    boolean first = true;
    String parent = null;
    int index = 1;
    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {
        
        if (tag.equals("ul")) {
            parent = "ul";
        } else if (tag.equals("ol")) {
            parent = "ol";
        }

        if (tag.equals("li")) {
            if (parent.equals("ul")) {
                if (first) {
                    output.append("\n\t•");
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    first = true;
                }
            } else{
                if (first) {
                    output.append("\n\t"+index+". ");
                    first = false;
                    index++;
                } else {
                    first = true;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

and for displaying the text...

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<ul><li>I am an Android developer</li><li>Another Item</li></ul>", null, new MyTagHandler()));
```

[Edit]

Kuitsi has also posted an really [good library](https://bitbucket.org/Kuitsi/android-textview-html-list) that does the same, got it from [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365740/1234007).

Comment: We used this approach in the end. Any unsupported HTML tags, we code in text ourselves. For now its just ol and ul, but we added in stacks to handle nesting of lists and storing indexes when nesting ol. In addition you can use the opening boolean parameter in replacement of first.

Comment: @Aman Gautam very awesome thanks for this! Do you have any idea how to  tab the text when it wraps more than 1 line? With this code after the 2nd line the text is aligned with the number rather than tabbed in to keep the number separate. I attempted a few things but I could not figure it out

Comment: same thing here, linebreaks in a list causes trobule with this approach.

Comment: Instead of using the pasted bullet character, it may be better to use the unicode character:

output.append("\n\t\u2022");

Comment: Thank you for this nice code, but I can't use it until we'll find a solution how to fix the multiple line indentation

Comment: This was the correct way to obtain the results I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: There's a crash you can get from this code snipped if the parent is null when you reach `if (parent.equals("ul"))`. This can occur when an `<li>` doesn't have either a `<ul>` or `<ol>` parent which isn't that uncommon of a scenario

Comment: @MartinPfeffer The answer was written 5+ years back. If something has changed in that time, please update the answer. I don't work on Android anymore.

Comment: TagHandler is used for tags which are not supported by platform. Now <ul>,<ol>,<li> are supported, so I recommend you to make custom tags inside your html string(file) for examplel: <customul>, <customol>, <customil>.

Answer (score 68):

Full sample project is located at https://bitbucket.org/Kuitsi/android-textview-html-list.
Sample picture is available at https://kuitsi.bitbucket.io/stackoverflow3150400_screen.png

This solution is closest to [masha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16169511/262462). Some code is also taken from inner class `android.text.Html.HtmlToSpannedConverter`. It supports nested ordered and unordered lists but too long texts in ordered lists are still aligned with item number rather than text. Mixed lists (ol and ul) needs some work too. Sample project contains implementation of [Html.TagHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html) which is passed to [Html.fromHtml(String, ImageGetter, TagHandler)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler%29).

<strike>Edit: For wider HTML tag support, https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner might also be worth trying.</strike>

Comment: No issue tracking in BitBucket repo, so posting here: you need to add checks [here](https://bitbucket.org/Kuitsi/android-textview-html-list/src/69949bd63422aeeefb79c67398dc14aab8806416/app/src/main/java/fi/iki/kuitsi/listtest/MyTagHandler.java?at=master#cl-86) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/Kuitsi/android-textview-html-list/src/69949bd63422aeeefb79c67398dc14aab8806416/app/src/main/java/fi/iki/kuitsi/listtest/MyTagHandler.java?at=master#cl-105) for `output.length() > 0` as in `if (output.length() > 0 && output.charAt(output.length() - 1) != '\n')`

Comment: Just to avoid other people wasting 2 hours on this, NightWhistler HtmlSpanner removes all accented characters for whatever unknown reason.

Comment: @Kuitsi thanks for the solution. There is one issue with it, when html text is "<ul><li>something</li></ul>", then the last letter in "something" is not displayed in the list.

Comment: This is a very good solution, BUT two drawbacks: 1) it **doesn't support Android ≥ 7** and 2) it doesn't put starting indent for first level of list.

Comment: @soshial you are right. Not working on Android 7. Ordered list shows as underscored list with bullets. How to handle this. Any idea?

Comment: it doesn't help when you have `ol`  with style. in this case, [NIghtWhistler/HtmlSpanner](https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner) works well.

Answer (score 25):

A small fix to Aman Guatam code. The function above has problem of rendering newline character. For example: if before `<li>` tag is a `<p>` tag, 2 newline characters are rendered. Here is upgraded code:

```
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Html.TagHandler;

public class ListTagHandler implements TagHandler {
    boolean first = true;

    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (tag.equals("li")) {
            char lastChar = 0;
            if (output.length() > 0)
                lastChar = output.charAt(output.length() - 1);
            if (first) {
                if (lastChar == '\n')
                    output.append("\t•  ");
                else
                    output.append("\n\t•  ");
                first = false;
            } else {
                first = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about ordered list?

Answer (score 19):

**WARNING**

As of Android 7 `android.text.Html` actually supports `li` and `ul` tags and uses a basic `BulletSpan()`, which means in the latest versions of Android the `Html.TagHandler`solutions posted here will be ignored

Make sure your code handles this change. In case you want a BulletSpan with a larger gap than the default, you can can replace it with another span:

```
val html = SpannableStringBuilder(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(source, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT))
val bulletSpans = html.getSpans<BulletSpan>(0, html.length)
bulletSpans.forEach {
    val spanStart = html.getSpanStart(it)
    val spanEnd = html.getSpanEnd(it)
    html.removeSpan(it)
    val bulletSpan = BulletSpan(gapWidthInDp, context.getColor(R.color.textColorBlack))
    html.setSpan(bulletSpan, spanStart, spanEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
}
```

Comment: But that new Html class is only available in Android `N` and above.

Comment: Yep - so you need to account for the fact that different OS versions will behave differently. Hence why I recommend a solution that finds and replaces the BulletSpan after the HTML has been parsed into different spans. The default implementation of versions after N will use a default margin, you can find and replace these with the margin you want.

Comment: Always keep up to date.

Answer (score 9):

Different solution using LeadingMarginSpan. Handles ordered and unordered lists as well as nesting.

```
public class ListTagHandler implements TagHandler
{
    private int                 m_index     = 0;
    private List< String >  m_parents   = new ArrayList< String >( );

    @Override
    public void handleTag( final boolean opening, final String tag, Editable output,    final XMLReader xmlReader )
    {
        if( tag.equals( "ul" ) || tag.equals( "ol" ) || tag.equals( "dd" ) )
        {
            if( opening )
            {
                m_parents.add( tag );
            }
            else m_parents.remove( tag );

            m_index = 0;
        }
        else if( tag.equals( "li" ) && !opening ) handleListTag( output );
    }

    private void handleListTag( Editable output )
    {
        if( m_parents.get(m_parents.size()-1 ).equals( "ul" ) )
        {
            output.append( "\n" );
            String[ ] split = output.toString( ).split( "\n" );

            int lastIndex = split.length - 1;
            int start = output.length( ) - split[ lastIndex ].length( ) - 1;
            output.setSpan( new BulletSpan( 15 * m_parents.size( ) ), start, output.length( ), 0 );
        }
        else if( m_parents.get(m_parents.size()-1).equals( "ol" ) )
        {
            m_index++ ;

            output.append( "\n" );
            String[ ] split = output.toString( ).split( "\n" );

            int lastIndex = split.length - 1;
            int start = output.length( ) - split[ lastIndex ].length( ) - 1;
            output.insert( start, m_index + ". " );
            output.setSpan( new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard( 15 * m_parents.size( ) ), start, output.length( ), 0 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using Spans but I can't get nested list working with this code. Both of lines `output.setSpan(...)` crashes with `java.lang.RuntimeException: PARAGRAPH span must start at paragraph boundary`

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution! It also indents multiple line texts

Comment: why do you use a Vector instead of a simple ArrayList ? a Vector is for multi threads...

Comment: @androiddeveloper c++ programmer, my bad, feel free to edit the answer

Comment: Thanks :) Working Perfectly... From now `<table>` tag also including in Supported tags by `HTML` in `TextView`

Comment: I have posted as Snippet http://www.androidsnippets.com/support-list-tag-of-html-in-textview-using-fromhtml

Comment: @PratikButani Your link is dead.

Comment: @masha This code doesn't seem to work well: On Android 8.1 (and maybe some below) it handles ordered lists like un-ordered lists (puts only bullets) and doesn't put space after the bullets. On Android 4.4, after each number with a dot, it goes to the next line. See here comparison between the 2 versions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/asQ5O.png .

Answer (score 8):

If you only need to format a list, keep it simple and copy/paste a unicode character in your TextView to achieve the same result.

• Unicode Character 'BULLET' (U+2022)

Answer (score 6):

I came here looking for TagHandler implementations. Both Truong Nguyen and Aman Guatam answers are very nice, but I needed a mixed version of both: I needed my solution not to overformat it and to be able to ressolve `<ol>` tags, since I'm parsing something like `<h3>title</h3><ol><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li></ol>`.

Here's my solution.

```
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Html.TagHandler;

public class MyTagHandler implements TagHandler {
    boolean first = true;
    String parent = null;
    int index = 1;

    public void handleTag(final boolean opening, final String tag,
            final Editable output, final XMLReader xmlReader) {

        if (tag.equals("ul")) {
            parent = "ul";
                    index = 1;
        } else if (tag.equals("ol")) {
            parent = "ol";
                    index = 1;
        }
        if (tag.equals("li")) {
            char lastChar = 0;
            if (output.length() > 0) {
                lastChar = output.charAt(output.length() - 1);
            }
            if (parent.equals("ul")) {
                if (first) {
                    if (lastChar == '\n') {
                        output.append("\t•  ");
                    } else {
                        output.append("\n\t•  ");
                    }
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    first = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (first) {
                    if (lastChar == '\n') {
                        output.append("\t" + index + ". ");
                    } else {
                        output.append("\n\t" + index + ". ");
                    }
                    first = false;
                    index++;
                } else {
                    first = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, since we are resetting the index value whenever a new list starts, it WILL NOT work if you nest lists like in `<ol><li>1<ol><li>1.1</li><li>1.2</li></ol><li>2</li></ol>`

1. 1

   1. 1.1
   2. 1.2

   2

With that code, you would get `1, 1, 2, 3` instead of `1, 1, 2, 2`.

Comment: This code works till version 23. How to make it work for 24 and above?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply replace the "li" with unicodes

```
    @Override
public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {

    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("li")) {
        if (opening) {
            output.append("\u2022 ");
        } else {
            output.append("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there ise a way of showing bullets in Android TextView. You can replace `<li>` tags with `&#149;` (which is HTML code for bullet).

If you want to try other list icons, use the preferred one from the table is this link;

http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: Didn't work for me. Instead, on Android 7.1.1 and 6.0.1, a box with an x through it appears instead of the bullet in the TextView.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Html.TagHandler`. Below can be used for kotlin

```
    class UlTagHandler : Html.TagHandler {
    override fun handleTag(
        opening: Boolean, tag: String, output: Editable,
        xmlReader: XMLReader
    ) {
        if (tag == "ul" && !opening) output.append("\n")
        if (tag == "li" && opening) output.append("\n\t•")
    }
}
```

and

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtmlText, null, UlTagHandler()));
```

Answer (score 2):

[Lord Voldermort's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546532/1073023) is a good starting point. However I required `ol` tag to display ordered list `1. 2. 3. ....` instead of bullets. Also, nested tags need special handling to work properly.

In my code, I have maintained stack(parentList) to keep track of opened and closed `ul` and `ol` tags and also to know the current open tag.
Also, a `levelWiseCounter` is used to maintain different counts in case of nested `ol` tags.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your string", null, new CustomTagHandler()));
```

.
.
.

```
private static class CustomTagHandler implements TagHandler
   {
      int level = 0;
      private LinkedList<Tag> parentList = new LinkedList<DetailFragment.CustomTagHandler.Tag>();
      private HashMap<Integer, Integer> levelWiseCounter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

      @Override
      public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader)
      {
         if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("ul") || tag.equalsIgnoreCase("ol"))
         {
            if (opening)
            {
               if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("ul"))
               {
                  parentList.push(Tag.UL);
               }
               else
               {
                  parentList.push(Tag.OL);
               }
               level++;
            }
            else
            {
               if (!parentList.isEmpty())
               {
                  parentList.pop();

                  //remove counter at that level, in any present.
                  levelWiseCounter.remove(level);
               }
               level--;
               if (level < 0)
               {
                  level = 0;
               }
            }
         }
         else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("li"))
         {
            if (opening && level > 0)
            {
               //new line check
               int length = output.toString().length();
               if (length > 0 && (output.toString().charAt(length - 1) == '\n'))
               {
               }
               else
               {
                  output.append("\n");
               }

               //add tabs as per current level of li
               for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
               {
                  output.append("\t");
               }

               // append dot or numbers based on parent tag
               if (Tag.UL == parentList.peek())
               {
                  output.append("•");
               }
               else
               {
                  //parent is OL. Check current level and retreive counter from levelWiseCounter
                  int counter = 1;
                  if (levelWiseCounter.get(level) == null)
                  {
                     levelWiseCounter.put(level, 1);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     counter = levelWiseCounter.get(level) + 1;
                     levelWiseCounter.put(level, counter);
                  }
                  output.append(padInt(counter) + ".");
               }

               //trailing tab
               output.append("\t");

            }
         }
      }

      /**
       * Add padding so that all numbers are aligned properly. Currently supports padding from 1-99.
       * 
       * @param num
       * @return
       */
      private static String padInt(int num)
      {
         if (num < 10)
         {
            return " " + num;
         }
         return "" + num;
      }

      private enum Tag
      {
         UL, OL
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the next code (based on [**this link**](https://bitbucket.org/Kuitsi/android-textview-html-list/src/60b6e8588fcd76dc744129b2963f8b47f659e6bd/src/fi/iki/kuitsi/listtest/MyTagHandler.java)) :

```
public class TextViewHtmlTagHandler implements TagHandler
  {
  /**
   * Keeps track of lists (ol, ul). On bottom of Stack is the outermost list
   * and on top of Stack is the most nested list
   */
  Stack<String>                   lists          =new Stack<String>();
  /**
   * Tracks indexes of ordered lists so that after a nested list ends
   * we can continue with correct index of outer list
   */
  Stack<Integer>                  olNextIndex    =new Stack<Integer>();
  /**
   * List indentation in pixels. Nested lists use multiple of this.
   */
  private static final int        indent         =10;
  private static final int        listItemIndent =indent*2;
  private static final BulletSpan bullet         =new BulletSpan(indent);

  @Override
  public void handleTag(final boolean opening,final String tag,final Editable output,final XMLReader xmlReader)
    {
    if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("ul"))
      {
      if(opening)
        lists.push(tag);
      else lists.pop();
      }
    else if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("ol"))
      {
      if(opening)
        {
        lists.push(tag);
        olNextIndex.push(Integer.valueOf(1)).toString();// TODO: add support for lists starting other index than 1
        }
      else
        {
        lists.pop();
        olNextIndex.pop().toString();
        }
      }
    else if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("li"))
      {
      if(opening)
        {
        if(output.length()>0&&output.charAt(output.length()-1)!='\n')
          output.append("\n");
        final String parentList=lists.peek();
        if(parentList.equalsIgnoreCase("ol"))
          {
          start(output,new Ol());
          output.append(olNextIndex.peek().toString()+". ");
          olNextIndex.push(Integer.valueOf(olNextIndex.pop().intValue()+1));
          }
        else if(parentList.equalsIgnoreCase("ul"))
          start(output,new Ul());
        }
      else if(lists.peek().equalsIgnoreCase("ul"))
        {
        if(output.charAt(output.length()-1)!='\n')
          output.append("\n");
        // Nested BulletSpans increases distance between bullet and text, so we must prevent it.
        int bulletMargin=indent;
        if(lists.size()>1)
          {
          bulletMargin=indent-bullet.getLeadingMargin(true);
          if(lists.size()>2)
            // This get's more complicated when we add a LeadingMarginSpan into the same line:
            // we have also counter it's effect to BulletSpan
            bulletMargin-=(lists.size()-2)*listItemIndent;
          }
        final BulletSpan newBullet=new BulletSpan(bulletMargin);
        end(output,Ul.class,new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(listItemIndent*(lists.size()-1)),newBullet);
        }
      else if(lists.peek().equalsIgnoreCase("ol"))
        {
        if(output.charAt(output.length()-1)!='\n')
          output.append("\n");
        int numberMargin=listItemIndent*(lists.size()-1);
        if(lists.size()>2)
          // Same as in ordered lists: counter the effect of nested Spans
          numberMargin-=(lists.size()-2)*listItemIndent;
        end(output,Ol.class,new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(numberMargin));
        }
      }
    else if(opening)
      Log.d("TagHandler","Found an unsupported tag "+tag);
    }

  private static void start(final Editable text,final Object mark)
    {
    final int len=text.length();
    text.setSpan(mark,len,len,Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
    }

  private static void end(final Editable text,final Class<?> kind,final Object... replaces)
    {
    final int len=text.length();
    final Object obj=getLast(text,kind);
    final int where=text.getSpanStart(obj);
    text.removeSpan(obj);
    if(where!=len)
      for(final Object replace : replaces)
        text.setSpan(replace,where,len,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return;
    }

  private static Object getLast(final Spanned text,final Class<?> kind)
    {
    /*
     * This knows that the last returned object from getSpans()
     * will be the most recently added.
     */
    final Object[] objs=text.getSpans(0,text.length(),kind);
    if(objs.length==0)
      return null;
    return objs[objs.length-1];
    }

  private static class Ul
    {
    }

  private static class Ol
    {
    }
  }
```

Comment: This answer has only slightly different formatting compared to the original source of this, which was created to support another answer to this same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17365740/262462 :)

Comment: true. didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem, that I always got an empty line after a list with @Kuitsis solution. I added a few lines in handleTag() and now the empty lines are gone:

```
@Override
public void handleTag(final boolean opening, final String tag, final Editable output, final XMLReader xmlReader) {
    if (UL_TAG.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
        if (opening) {   // handle <ul>
            lists.push(new Ul());
        } else {   // handle </ul>
            lists.pop();
            if (output.length() > 0 && output.charAt(output.length() - 1) == '\n') {
                output.delete(output.length() - 1, output.length());
            }
        }
    } else if (OL_TAG.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
        if (opening) {   // handle <ol>
            lists.push(new Ol()); // use default start index of 1
        } else {   // handle </ol>
            lists.pop();
            if (output.length() > 0 && output.charAt(output.length() - 1) == '\n') {
                output.delete(output.length() - 1, output.length());
            }
        }
    } else if (LI_TAG.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
        if (opening) {   // handle <li>
            lists.peek().openItem(output);
        } else {   // handle </li>
            lists.peek().closeItem(output, lists.size());
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("TagHandler", "Found an unsupported tag " + tag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a confirmation to what kassim has stated. there is fragmentation. i found how to resolve this. i have to rename `<li>` and ul to a custom tag. so:

```
myHTML.replaceAll("</ul>","</customTag>").replaceAll("<ul>","<customTag>");
//likewise for li
```

then in my handler i can look for that customTag (which does nothing) and make it do something.

```
//now my handler can handle the customtags. it was ignoring them after nougat. 
 public class UlTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler {
        //for ul in nougat and up this tagHandler is completely ignored
        @Override
        public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output,
                              XMLReader xmlReader) {

            if (tag.equals("customtag2") && opening)
            output.append("\n\t\u25CF\t");
        if (tag.equals("customtag2") && !opening)
            output.append("\n");
        }
    }
```

this should make it work for all versions of android.