# ANDROID: Show bullets points in android application

Tags: android

I want to show bullet points in android app like image below
[image]
I tried a  lot of things like using ASCII Code but nothing is working

Comment: maybe try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992794/how-to-add-bulleted-list-to-android-application)?

Comment: another approach is you can use `BulletSpan

Comment: Simply use `\u2219` DIRECTLY as your bullet character (it doesn't need `HTML.FromHtml()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `&#8226;`

OR

Just copy this bullet `" • "` and paste in your text view's text