# Creating list of text with "\n" tag within string from remote database not working

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a column in my database that is supposed to be a list of product details. After researching how to create a string on the next line, I put the "\n" tag in between each line. But instead of showing:

- Weight
- Height
- Manufacturer
- Model number

I am getting this:

> Weight\nHeight\nManufacturer\nModel number

I am using Volley to get the row/column from the database like this:

```
response.getJSONObject(i).getString("details")
```

Then in my adapter, I am using this:

```
public String getDetails(){
    return details;
}
```

Comment: So you are inserting into mysql... are you parameterizing your query @ insert?

Comment: @YaWang No. I'm not "inserting" into MySql. I'm retrieving the data to display within an Android app

Comment: I see your android app doesn't recognize  that \n is meant to be a bullet? If so you aren't looking for \n but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992794/how-to-add-bulleted-list-to-android-application

Comment: @YaWang Although that may work, I don't really want a bulleted list. Just each item on a separate line. I thought that \n or \r\n would work as it does if coming from the strings.xml file but for some reason it doesn't when coming from a network source

Comment: Run System.getProperty("line.separator") print out that result in your app and make sure it is = to \n also I do think you can only do new lines in a textview so make sure its a textview

Comment: @YaWang I've confirmed that it is a textview. I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean by running System.get property("line.separator"). Could you explain please? I've never used that before