# Bullet point HTML in aTextView does not have proper indent

Tags: android, html, textview

I would like to have an indent or 2 spaces after the bullet. However, when I add &nbsp ; I still see the underline. And I wonder if there is not a better way to solve this? Also, when looking at the bullet, it is missing some pixels on the left side. Is this normal?

Solution must also work till API 18.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val someText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.someTextView)
    val url = "<ul><li><a href='https://www.google.nl'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Awesome clickable link</a></li></ul>"
    setEditText(someText, url)
}

fun setEditText(textView: TextView, text: String) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        textView.text = Html.fromHtml(text, Html.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE)
    } else {
        textView.text = Html.fromHtml(text)
    }
    textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/someTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990755/add-bullets-with-proper-formatting-in-android) does not work because I am getting html tags .

Comment: What do you mean exactly with: "when looking at the bullet, it is missing some pixels on the left side. Is this normal?" Should it be left aligned as the blue Box?

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-left` to your **`<a href...`** element and also a property **`display:block`** and force all with **`!important`** and remove **`&nbsp;`**:

```
...
val url = "<ul><li><a href='https://www.google.nl' style='display:block !important; margin-left:30px !important;'>Awesome clickable link</a></li></ul>"
...
```