# Can I just copy a bullet icon and will it appear as normal bullet on mobile devices?

Tags: html, list, html-lists, bullet

when pasting a simple bullet icon like this "•" from this website https://www.piliapp.com/symbol/bullet-point/ into your html code does it also appear as a normal bullet icon on mobile devices?

Comment: You should be using `unordered list` -- `<ul>`  -->  [Unordered Lists](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists_unordered.asp)

Comment: Can't you test it and see?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992794/how-to-add-bulleted-list-to-android-application

Answer (score -1):

You really should be using `ul` to create bulletpoints - otherwise your applications accessibility will be significantly reduced - always aim to use semantic elements in your HTML where possible.

To answer your question though, provided you use the copied snippet in an appropriate element (`div`, `span`, `p`) for example - then the bullet point will render correctly.