# Android : assets dir and multi language

Tags: android, localization, assets

Good morning. Into my android application I have in assets directory a file changelog. I have creato also the directory assets-it and I have put into the file changelog in italian language but when I start the application it always display the file into assets directory also if the device language is set to italian. Why ?

Answer (score 2):

That is the expected behavior.  Resources in `res/` can be localized in that manner, but the `assets/` directory cannot.

Since it's just a changelog, I'd recommend storing it as a localized string resource in `res/values-LOCALE/`.  If you really want localization of assets, you could manually recreate it by getting the current locale and loading, e.g. `assets/changelog-en`, vs. `assets/changelog-it`, but I think that would generally not be a good idea, and it certainly isn't necessary in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. put both changelog files into assets folder:

Path is for example: assets/**en**/changelog_file and assets/**it**/changelog_file

2. enter this into your **values**/strings.xml:

`<string name="changelog_file">file:///android_asset/en/changelog_file</string>`

3. put in your **values-it**/strings.xml:

`<string name="changelog_file">file:///android_asset/it/changelog_file</string>`

Like this you can call the string from the code:
getResources().getString(R.string.changelog_file) and it will call the values-en or values-it according to device locale.