# change the language of the raw folder

Tags: android, directory, idioms

I have in my project raw folder with several mp3 within.

I want, depending on the language of the phone, using a mp3 or other
in the "values", I can change the language (values_en, values_es, etc) ... but as I do with the raw folder?

I appreciate any help

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in this answer, it seems like it isn't supported, but has some workarounds:

[localization of assets files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427933/localization-of-assets-files)