# Can underline words in TextView text

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there possibility in android to provide TextView some text in Java code with setText(text) function with basic tags like  and  to make marked words underlined ?

Comment: [**This will help you,**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout)
this is the example by which you can `underline` your textview text and also `italic`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display HTML in TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, you can, use the Html.fromhtml() method:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("this is <u>underlined</u> text"));
```

Comment: well, I am facing a problem. Here is the line of codes that is not working.
`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.have_activation_code)));`
`<string name="have_activation_code"><u>I have activation code</u></string>`

Comment: @mahbub.kuet You have to put your HTML string into <![CDATA[]]>. So <string name="have_activation_code"><![CDATA[<u>I have activation code</u>]]></string>

Comment: `Html.fromHtml` is deprecated now

Answer (score 34):

Define a string as:

```
<resources>
    <string name="your_string">This is an <u>underline</u> text demo for TextView.</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Yes but you can use it for dynamic strings by using Html.fromHtml(), check above answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8558246/379693

Comment: @PareshMayani but beware, there are tags not supported by `Html.fromHtml()`. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3150456/1987045

Answer (score 10):

You can use UnderlineSpan from SpannableString class:

```
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(<your text>);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
```

Then just use `textView.setText(content);`

Answer (score 3):

```
tobeunderlined= <u>some text here which is to be underlined</u> 

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("some string"+tobeunderlined+"somestring"));
```

Answer (score 3):

## Most Easy Way

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText("some text");
setUnderLineText(tv, "some");
```

> Also support TextView childs like EditText, Button, Checkbox

```
public void setUnderLineText(TextView tv, String textToUnderLine) {
        String tvt = tv.getText().toString();
        int ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToUnderLine, 0);

        UnderlineSpan underlineSpan = new UnderlineSpan();
        SpannableString wordToSpan = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
        for (int ofs = 0; ofs < tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {
            ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToUnderLine, ofs);
            if (ofe == -1)
                break;
            else {
                wordToSpan.setSpan(underlineSpan, ofe, ofe + textToUnderLine.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                tv.setText(wordToSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want

**- Clickable underline text?**

**- Underline multiple parts of TextView?**

Then [Check This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46390973/6891563)