# How to highlight Multiple words in EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, spannablestring

Currently I'm developing Spelling & Grammar checking app. It has EditText where user can input text & one button called "Check Text " upon click on  button app will call LanguageTool API to check text & returns JSON response with result .

Here is screenshot of app :[image]

Here is code which I have tried so far for highlighting multiple words but this code only highlights last word from array which I have created:

```
for (int i = 0; i < errorStrings.size(); i++) {

// Here textToCheck is EditText & errorStrings is ArrayList of type WrongString class which i have created to hold Error string , offset & length.

Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(texttoSend);
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),errorStrings.get(i).getOffset(),
                                        (errorStrings.get(i).getOffset()+errorStrings.get(i).getLength()), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                            textToCheck.setText(wordtoSpan);
}
```

Comment: Hi @DeepShah, any suggestions on replacing tapped word with custom words in edit text ? I am doing same functionality any suggestions would be great help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have wrote a simple method that allow you pass `TextView` (or child classes `Button`, `Edittext` etc.).

**1. If you want to highlight a text like in find word in paragraph. You can use below method like.**

```
setHighLightedText(yourTextView_Edittext_Button, "a");
```

Which gives you result like this.

[image]

```
    /**
     * use this method to highlight a text in TextView
     * @param tv TextView or Edittext or Button or child of TextView class
     * @param textToHighlight Text to highlight
     */
    public void setHighLightedText(TextView tv, String textToHighlight) {
        String tvt = tv.getText().toString();
        int ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, 0);
        Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
        for (int ofs = 0; ofs < tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {
            ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, ofs);
            if (ofe == -1)
                break;
            else {
                wordToSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), ofe, ofe + textToHighlight.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                tv.setText(wordToSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

**2. If you want make clickable highlighted text (like click on terms & condition text) then use this code as below:**

```
 setClickableHighLightedText(yourTextView_Edittext_Button, "go to settings", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: do your stuff here 
        }
    });
```

Which gives you result like

[image]

```
/**
 * use this method to set clickable highlighted a text in TextView
 *
 * @param tv              TextView or Edittext or Button or child of TextView class
 * @param textToHighlight Text to highlight
 */
public void setClickableHighLightedText(TextView tv, String textToHighlight, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    String tvt = tv.getText().toString();
    int ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, 0);
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            if (onClickListener != null) onClickListener.onClick(textView);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setColor(0xff0000ff);
            ds.setUnderlineText(true);
        }
    };
    SpannableString wordToSpan = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {
        ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, ofs);
        if (ofe == -1)
            break;
        else {
            wordToSpan.setSpan(clickableSpan, ofe, ofe + textToHighlight.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            tv.setText(wordToSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }
}
```

**This is a workaround, you can customise spans according to your need. Some good tutorials [Android text styles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary) and [one other](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/)**

Comment: Hi @Khemu , any idea on replacing a tapped word with custom suggested words in edit text ?

Comment: Hi deep, 
I edited my answer with your requirement, Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -

```
  TextView myTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  String  textString = "StackOverFlow Rocks!!!"; 
  Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(textString);
  spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 14, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  myTV.setText(spanText);
```

[Here is another post with similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview)

Comment: @Deep Shah Why don't you store the error strings in a different list and highlight the errors separately? Can you post the code before the for loop also? It'll be more clear. I think the mistake is here `textToCheck.setSelection(errorStrings.get(i).getOffset(),(errorStrings.get(i).getOffset()+errorStrings.get(i).getLength()));
` Please post the image of output that you're receiving.

Comment: Hi , I have updated code . I would prefer to display errors in edittext instead of TextView so , they can edit immediately from there.