# not able to change color of a part of text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestringbuilder

I want to change the color of some part of text in EditText. I am trying following code, but it is not working.

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb=new SpannableStringBuilder(expression);
ForegroundColorSpan fcs=new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(181,1,1));
ssb.setSpan(fcs,startIndex,endIndex,SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
expressionEditText.setText(ssb);
expressionTextView.setText(ssb);
```

> `startIndex` and `endIndex` are the indices in the expression for which
>   the color needs to be changed.
>
> This code works fine for the 'expressionTextView' but not for 
>   'expressionEditText'.

**xml part:**

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/expression_edit_text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:layout_above="@id/expression_text_view"
android:gravity="bottom|end"
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:textSize="45sp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:inputType="text"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/expression_text_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:gravity="right"
android:textSize="50sp"/>
```

**example:**

```
expression="I want color to be changed";
startIndex=2;
endIndex=5;
```

In expressionTextView "wan" color will be the specified color.
In expressionEditText there will not be any color change.

Comment: Add your Xml part .

Comment: @ADM added the xml part

Comment: Can you add the current result output. Screenshot. And a sample expression too.

Comment: @ADM I have added the example description.

Comment: Code is OK . And  It will work for static text In `Edittext` if you want a Span input then you should use a `TextWatcher`. What exactly the requirement ?

Comment: See the answer Deepanshu

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.

As i answered before in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46390221/6891563).

You can achieve this by the following code, which i use always. I tried to make this method as simple as i could. You have to pass just your `Editext` and `TextToHighLight` in below method.

If you require clickable span you can go to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46390973/6891563). Feel free to ask in comment if you need TextWatcher too.

```
public void setHighLightedText(EditText editText, String textToHighlight) {
    String tvt = editText.getText().toString();
    int ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, 0);
    Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(editText.getText());

    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {


        ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, ofs);
        if (ofe == -1)
            break;
        else {
            WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), ofe, ofe + textToHighlight.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            editText.setText(WordtoSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    }
}
```