# How to make part of recycler View bold?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have one EditText and one recyclerview. I add a List to my recyclerview and now I want to make the first letters bold of the recycleview. But I want to make only the letters bold which are written in my editText, so I cannot define it just in xml. How can I make part of my List in bold, like

**Bo**ld1

**Bo**ld2

Here is my layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Abfahrtsmonitor">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Suche"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/Recycleview"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="494dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is part of my kotlin code:

```
class Abfahrtsmonitor : AppCompatActivity() {
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.abfahrtsmonitor)
    Recycleview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
HaltestellenEingabe_dummy.add(helpname)
Recycleview.adapter = listadapter(HaltestellenEingabe_dummy, this)
  var textview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editText)
    textview.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            println("1")
            HaltestellenEingabe_dummy.clear()
            for(i in 0..Haltestellen.size-1){
                var inttext=0
                var inteingabe=0
                if(textview.text.toString()==Haltestellen[i].subSequence(0,textview.length()).toString()){     //If the same letters are used
                    HaltestellenEingabe_dummy.add(Haltestellen[i]) // Here I would like to define the layout of my Segments.
                }
            }
            Recycleview.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })
```

Here the ListAdapter:

```
class listadapter(val items : ArrayList<String>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

// Gets the number of animals in the list
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

// Inflates the item views
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return     ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listviewfile, parent, false))
}

// Binds each animal in the ArrayList to a view
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder?.haltestellenliste?.text = items.get(position)
}
}
class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
// Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
val haltestellenliste = view.aufzaehlunghaltestellen
}
```

Comment: Use a `StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)` and apply it to a `SpannableStringBuilder`?

Comment: Can you post the `listadapter` code?

Comment: Listadapter is updated

Comment: Can you give an example @Michael, I am fairly new to kotlin.

Comment: This is solution, you will implement like this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46390973/6891563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onBindViewHolder`, where you're setting the text, you can use `SpannableStringBuilder` to bold the first letter:

```
holder?.haltestellenliste?.text = SpannableStringBuilder(items[position]).apply{
    setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
}
```