# Show <ul> <li> in android textview

Tags: android, html, formatting, textview

I have String with ul and li in it. And I am trying to show them in HTML formatting in textview. 
`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtmlText));` 
But textview shows the plain text. How can I have the ul and li tags formatted in textview?

Comment: KIndly check this post:

[Stack Overflow Post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html List tag not working in android textview. what can i do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150400/html-list-tag-not-working-in-android-textview-what-can-i-do)

Answer (score 52):

You can use Html.TagHandler.

In your case it will be like this:

```
public class UlTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler{
    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output,
                          XMLReader xmlReader) {
            if(tag.equals("ul") && !opening) output.append("\n");
            if(tag.equals("li") && opening) output.append("\n\t•");
    }
}
```

and

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtmlText, null, new UlTagHandler()));
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!!

Comment: nice one! just the indenting issue on bullets with multiple lines of text

Comment: Newer versions of Android seem to support this tag. Important point, according to the documentation of UITagHandler : "Is notified when HTML tags are encountered that the parser does not know how to interpret.".

It only be called when the tag cannot be interpreted.

Comment: Good answer! Work for API 26

Comment: @MikeAxle can remove \t

Comment: it adds extra line in this situation </p><ul><li> .  /p tag is the first closing tag in my html

Answer (score 13):

**Tags Supported in String Resources**

Tags in static string resources are parsed by android.content.res.StringBlock, which is a hidden class. I've looked through the class and determined which tags are supported:

```
<a> (supports attributes "href")
<annotation>
<b>
<big>
<font> (supports attributes "height", "size", "fgcolor" and "bicolor", as integers)
<i>
<li>
<marquee>
<small>
<strike>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

**Tags Supported by Html.fromHtml()**

For some reason, Html.fromHtml() handles a different set of of tags than static text supports. Here's a list of the tags (gleaned from Html.java's source code):

```
<a> (supports attribute "href")
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div>
<em>
<font> (supports attributes "color" and "face")
<i>
<img> (supports attribute "src". Note: you have to include an ImageGetter to handle retrieving a Drawable for this tag)
<p>
<small>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

see this [link](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html) for more details

Comment: how come "li" tag is supported and yet the container isn't?

Answer (score 6):

see [HTML Tags Supported By TextView](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)  both **ul** and **li** tags are not Supported by [android.text.Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class.

**SOLUTION :** you can display these tags using [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) or by [TagHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html)

for more help see this post:

[Html List tag not working in android textview. what can i do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150400/html-list-tag-not-working-in-android-textview-what-can-i-do)

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150400/html-list-tag-not-working-in-android-textview-what-can-i-do maybe helpful

Comment: @aman.nepid : you can handle these tags by using TagHandler or webview

Answer (score 4):

According to the answer below, you can not use every HTML tag here;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150456/2275962

But, sure, there ise a way of showing bullets in Android TextView. You can replace `<li>` tags with `&#149;` (which is HTML code for bullet).

If you want to try other list icons, use the preferred one from the table is this link;

http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: **&#149;** doesnt work for me. I have to use **&#8226;**

Answer (score 4):

A really easy way to make things work for API level M (23) and lower
From your HTML string you can use the following:

```
private fun String.formattedHtml(): String {
    // Work around for API Versions lower than N, Html.fromHtml does not render list items correctly
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        this.replace("<ul>", "")
            .replace("</ul>", "")
            .replace("<li>", "<p>• ")
            .replace("</li>", "</p>")
    } else {
        this
    }
}
```

Then, you can use:

```
Html.fromHtml("<ul><li> test </li></ul>".formattedHtml())
```

No need for `TagHandler` for API N and up, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40524835, `android.text.Html` supports `li` and `ul` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Im my case my data is coming down from an API call.  I still needed the output to match the format of my app so I wrap the HTML string in formatting tags to display in my WebView:

```
public static String formatHtmlString(String stringIn) {

    String format = "<html>"
            + "  <head>"
            + "    <style type='text/css'>"
            + "      body { "
            + "           font-family: \"HelveticaNeue-Light\", \"Helvetica Neue Light\"; "
            + "           font-size:14px;" + "           color:#000;"
            + "      }" + "      b { " + "           font-size:14px;"
            + "       }" + "      i { " + "           font-size:10px;"
            + "           color:#333333;" + "           opacity:0.75;"
            + "       }" + "    </style>" + "  </head>" + "  <body>"
            + stringIn + "</body>" + "</html>";

    return format;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm getting a list of String (from backend as a JSON Response), then render the HTML manually using this approach for `TextView` only:

**In Kotlin**

```
// ViewUtils.kt
@file:JvmName("ViewUtils")

package com.company

private fun List<String>.joinToBulletList(): String =
        joinToString(prefix = "<ul>", postfix = "</ul>", separator = "\n") {
            "<li> $it</li>"
        }

fun TextView.renderToHtmlWithBulletList(contents: List<String>) {
    val content = contents.joinToBulletList()

    val html: Spannable = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Html.fromHtml(content, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT, null, null) as Spannable
    } else {
        Html.fromHtml(content, null, null) as Spannable
    }

    text = html
}

// AnyActivity.kt
val contents = listOf("desc 1", "desc 2", "desc 3")
textViewFromXml.renderToHtmlWithBulletList(contents)
```

**In Java**

```
// AnyActivity.java
List<String> contents = new String["desc 1", "desc 2", "desc 3"];
ViewUtils.renderToHtmlWithBulletList(textViewFromXml, contents)
```

Notice the `@file:JvmName("ViewUtils")` it is useful to change the file name so Java code can call it `ViewUtils.java` instead of `ViewUtilsKt.java`. See [here for more detail](https://dogwood008.github.io/kotlin-web-site-ja/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions)

P.S: Please feel free to edit this