# Replace HTML tags with String tags

Tags: android, html, string

By that, i mean if a String contains **HTML** tags like `<br></br>` they must be converted to `\n`.

I tried this:

```
String formatted = android.text.Html.fromHtml(nonFormatted).toString();
```

But this seems to just remove all the HTML tags.

**Input:**

```
String nonFormatted = "<ul><li>Android v4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) OS<\/li><li>2 MP Primary Camera<\/li><li>3-inch TFT Capacitive Touchscreen<\/li><li>850 MHz Processor<\/li><li>QWERTY Keypad<\/li><li>FM Radio<\/li><li>Wi-Fi Enabled<\/li><li>Expandable Storage Capacity of 32 GB<\/li><\/ul>";
```

**Output after using android.text.Html.fromHtml(nonFormatted).toString();**

```
String formatted = Android v4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) OS2 MP Primary Camera3-inch TFT Capacitive Touchscreen850 MHz ProcessorQWERTY KeypadFM RadioWi-Fi EnabledExpandable Storage Capacity of 32 GB
```

But on the website it looks like this:

[image]

I want my java String to be like the one in the image, instead of bullets, a new line character.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Html.fromHtml(string) just support some html tags like: br p div em b strong a u sup sub... but it doesn't support ul, li tags so you can try to display these tags using `WebView or TagHandler`. "`TagHanlder is notified when HTML tags are encountered that the parser does not know how to interpret`".These links will show you how to do that:

[Show <ul> <li> in android textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214001/show-ul-li-in-android-textview)

[Html List tag not working in android textview. what can i do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150400/html-list-tag-not-working-in-android-textview-what-can-i-do)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some parsing to properly replace the tags for whitespaces generically.. try exploring [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), it is a very powerful library that allows you to whitelist tags, clean up HTML, select and find tags, removing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple regular expression replace could sove this issue. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html