# Set TextView with Bullets and Number for HTML String

Tags: android, textview

I have String which contains HTML data with `<ol>` and `<ul>` tag. How to set both in TextView. I am able to set Bullets but not number format. What I did is here:

```
String html_title = demoList.get(position - 1).getText();
String li = html_title.replace("<li>", " \u25CF");
String mal = li.replace("</li>", "<br/>");
String main_hrml = mal.replace("\t", "\n").replace("\n\n", "\n").trim();

setTextViewHTML(((DemoViewHolderSecond) holder).demoSecondItemInitView.type_1_bodyTxt, main_html);


private void setTextViewHTML(TextView type_1_bodyTxt, String main_html) {
    CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(main_html);
    SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
    URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);
    for (URLSpan span : urls) {
        makeLinkClickable(strBuilder, span);
    }

    if (main_html.contains("<p>")){
        if (!main_html.contains("<ul")) {
            GetDeviceResolution getDeviceResolution = new GetDeviceResolution((CoverDetailsActivity) context);
            type_1_bodyTxt.setPadding(0, 0, 0, -(int) (getDeviceResolution.setHeight(0.06)));
        }else{
            GetDeviceResolution getDeviceResolution = new GetDeviceResolution((CoverDetailsActivity) context);
            type_1_bodyTxt.setPadding(0, 0, 0, -(int) (getDeviceResolution.setHeight(0.02)));
        }
    }
    type_1_bodyTxt.setText(strBuilder);
    type_1_bodyTxt.setLinkTextColor(Color.RED);

    removeLine(type_1_bodyTxt, main_html);
    type_1_bodyTxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Comment: The problem is only you want number instead of bullets ?? right ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show <ul> <li> in android textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214001/show-ul-li-in-android-textview)

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your code as stated below:

Add this method to your class or in any singleton class

```
public class UlTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler{
    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output,
                          XMLReader xmlReader) {
        if(tag.equals("ul")&& !opening) output.append("\n");
        if(tag.equals("li")&& opening) output.append("\n" +Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
    }
}
```

Now `setText` to your `TextView` or `EditText` element

```
 String your_html_string= "<ul>\n" +
            "  <li>Coffee</li>\n" +
            "  <li>Tea</li>\n" +
            "  <li>Milk</li>\n" +
            "</ul>";

btnSubmit.setText(Html.fromHtml(your_html_string, null, new UlTagHandler()));
```

The above code is for  tag only. For  tag you can update yourself :D

Rest you need to do is to set property of your `EditText` or `TextView` element
height to `wrapContent` do not assign some fixed height.

Comment: Sorry but I do then I wont able to get <ul> and Link available in the string

Comment: if your string contains real HTML data and you need to print that to your textview, this is the easiest and correct approach to achieve. Source provided by android itself.

Comment: It will show HTML data i Agree but if you want Spannable then it wont work

Comment: @Target If you are using more than very simple HTML, you should use a `WebView` instead of a `TextView`.

Comment: @Target will update in sometime after testing the same.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you but My all data is reflecting inside RecyclerView So I can't :(

Comment: @AnkushBist Thank you  :)

Comment: @Target code update successfully. And working fine for me

Comment: default Html conversion do not support unorderedList and orderList. huh