# TextView with html table

Tags: android

I have a problem. I want to put in to the "TextView" html format text. I add the  like below.

```
<string name="text"><![CDATA[<table><tr><th bgcolor= #FF0000>some text</th></tr> <tr><td bgcolor= #FF0000> some text</td></tr>]]></string>
```

and put it into the TextView as:

```
mInfoText.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text)));
```

but after run application, displayed text in TextView is not formatted.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Android TextView doesn't support the Table tag and that's the reason you can't see it in a formatted way. You must use a WebView for this purpose.

To know what are the tags supported check this [Html List tag not working in android textview. what can i do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3150400/603744)

Comment: Agree with you. And if OP still want to display this HTML then he must use WebView instead.

Comment: @PareshMayani May `WebView` use with `ListView` is Problematic then what should i do?

Comment: @ツPratikButaniツ Can you please be more specific about the question? Being an experienced SO user, don't you think you should provide more details while asking a question? :)

Answer (score 3):

try whit WebView

```
String html = "<table><tr><th>text1</th></tr><tr><td>text2</td></tr></table>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```