# How to show Html format of Tables in Textview?

Tags: android, textview

How to show Html format of Tables in Textview in android?

[image]

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13799882/3505534

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextView with html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799856/textview-with-html-table)

Answer (score 3):

Use `WebView` to load html Tables

```
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**JAVA code**

```
WebView webView=findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadData(htmlStringData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: `<table>` isn't a supported HTML tag to use with `Html.fromHtml`