# Android - Send email with Gmail with unordered list html tags

Tags: android, html, email, gmail

Is it possible to send emails with bulleted list html tag?
I try to do the following:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("<html><body>" + label + "<br>" + "<ul>");
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            builder.append("<li>" + wishes.get(i).getName() + "</li>");
        }
        builder.append("</ul></body></html>");

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        emailIntent.setType("text/html"); 
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList); 
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));  
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

But i just see text and not bulleted list in Gmail.
Thanks in advance

Comment: your html text first convert into htmlentity and then send :)

Answer (score 1):

`HTML.fromHtml()` doesn't support `<ul><ol><li>` tags refer [Html List tag not working in android textview. what can i do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150400/html-list-tag-not-working-in-android-textview-what-can-i-do) to solve this issue you can format the list manually by adding line breaks,white spaces and bullets