# WebView won't display static HTML in 4.2.2, but works in 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I can't get a WebView to display static HTML. It works in Android 2.3.3 but not in 4.2.2. No similar questions appear relevant, as I'm not using Javascript, HTTPS, and I tried clicking on the view. I tried the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

TmpActivity.java

```
public class TmpActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tmp);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.loadData("<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>","texl/html","UTF-8");
    }
```

activity_tmp.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TmpActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Emulator running 2.3.3

[image: Imgur]

Emulator running 4.2.2

[image: Imgur]

There are no errors in the logs. The only error is

> 05-25 00:56:20.563: E/Trace(4140): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: Not that this is the issue, but shouldn't it be text/html (not texl/html?)

Comment: Actually, that could well be the issue. Certainly, `WebView` can display content via `loadData()`, as it has for years, such as in this sample app: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WebKit/Browser3

Comment: @powerj1984 Oh snap! 4 hours on a typo! Curse you Android!

Comment: doh, I guess I'll add that as an answer then :)

Comment: @powerj1984  I found where I copied it from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150400/html-list-tag-not-working-in-android-textview-what-can-i-do

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo

texl/html -> text/html

Comment: I found where I copied it from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150400/html-list-tag-not-working-in-android-textview-what-can-i-do