# dynamical item list or list in item list in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

**How Create a dynamical Item list Or item in another item list like as BEETALK Android Software**

---

hello guys. i'm searching for how i can add description on a item of list onClick event.
like as contact list beetalk.

i wanna click on item1 and see description1 and when click on item2 description1 hide and description2 show and the end if item1 click and desc1 showing close desc1.

**step 0 :**

- item1
- item2

**step 1 :**

- item1
- desc1
- item2

**step 2 :**

- item1
- item2
- desc2

**step 3 :**

- item1
- item2

do you have any idea!

Comment: Have you tried using a dialog instead of adding description in your listview

Comment: i try that before but must be a way for dynamical item list for adding and removing on click or move a item in listview for showing desc.

Comment: Did you try `ExpandableListView` ?

Answer (score 0):

Create one `setSelected(int position)` method in the your list adapter. and from your `onlistitemclick` call it passing the clicked position.

edit your adapter code as following.

```
 int selectedPosition = -1;
 public void setSelected(int position)
{
    selectedPosition= position;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // your adapter code
    if(position==selectedPosition)
         description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: there is any way to add item for description on listview dynamically!

Comment: Then you can try something like this

    mAdapterView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
     int position, long arg3) {
    
   TextView description= new TextView(getActivity());
    description.setText("description");                 currentView = ((LinearLayout)arg0.getChildAt(position));
                        currentView.addView(description);
                       
}

Comment: But since you want to show only one description at a time in the listView, it will be tedious to remove view from previous adapterView and keep it for currently selected only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**ExpandableListView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), example [**here**](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html).

1. Define two XML layouts for Group view and Child view, add `TextView` to each layout for showing item text and description.
2. In code, set *Item text* to group's `TextView` and *Description* to child `TextView`, all children views will be hidden initially.
3. Use `ExpandableListView`'s `collapseGroup()` and `expandGroup()` methods to collapse or expand the groups.

For example, to collapse expanded groups before showing Description, first define `getGroupCount()` method in your `ListAdapter` class:

```
@Override
  public int getGroupCount() {
    return yourList.size();
}
```

then call this method to collapse previously expanded groups:

```
private void collapseAll() {
  int cnt = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
     yourList.collapseGroup(i);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can use [**TagHandler**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html) class with examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546532/855728) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9649408/855728) to show dynamic child list on child's `TextView` by using:

```
Html.fromHtml("<ul><li>Item 1</li>...</ul>", null, new MyTagHandler()))
```

For that you need to transform child list's item text to HTML text by iterating over your dynamic `List/ArrayList` and making/appending HTML tags with `string` data inside them.

Comment: i try before expandable list view but there is inner list on list i wanna add dynamically item to list and remove it.

Comment: See the Edit, you can use TagHandler class to show dynamic child list on child view, it's upto you how you make it !