# How to display formatted HTML in a TextView

Tags: android

I know I can use:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("html stuff"))
```

[but that doesn't know how to handle lists and a lot of other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150456/331021)

It also adds a lot of padding for some reason and overall seems like not a great solution.

I tried using WebViews in place of TextViews. However, that's extremely expensive, so it's not an option.

This seems like such a standard thing, there has to be a way to do this nicely or a library for it, or is there?

Comment: using a WebView is probably the easiest solution..

Comment: @Frame91 That's in no way a solution, a WebView is not a replacement for a TextView, it slows down the app a lot when I have 5 WebViews in one page rendered at once

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3150456/1484047 <-- see this link. Afaik ul, li are not supported by TextView. Using a WebView or parsing your text and insertig them in a listview would be your only solutions

Comment: This is definitely a gap in Android.  I don't know of anything offhand.  You can cast around on GitHub for something.

I had a bunch of bullet list items defined in strings.xml and I got so tired of the clunky layout workarounds that I wrote my own TextView subclass just to handle the proper indenting for bullets.

Comment: @kris I honestly don't know why android development is so terrible

Comment: I posted some code in an answer, maybe that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to implement a TagHandler and pass it to fromHtml. There is already a nice one here:

https://github.com/sufficientlysecure/html-textview

The only problem is that there will be some extra space at the end for w/e reason. You can write a simple function to trim those extra newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code from my `TextView` subclass for handling bullets, I left out the easy part.

```
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<Integer> markers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    /*
     *  Code to parse through text, remove tags, build up modified text in 
     *  StringBuilder and mark the bullet paragraph boundaries goes here.
     *  Left as an exercise for the reader.
     */

    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(sb.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i += 2) {
        int start = markers.get(i);
        int end = markers.get(i+1);
        spannableString.setSpan(new BulletSpan(bulletGap), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_PARAGRAPH);
    }

    super.setText(spannableString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

Note: If I remember correctly, Android *really really* wants that Paragraph Span to end with a newline character.

Also I tried but couldn't figure out how to use `LineHeightSpan` to make the first and last lines of the bullet span paragraph a little higher.

If you want a number (ordered) list, you're on your own.