# Android: How to display a String which has HTML tags in a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have tried

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString));
```

- there is no use. i.e., all the HTML tags are displayed as it is.

I've tried

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Now, images will appear like a small tiny blue squares. (not the actual images).

I have a String Variable which has some text and basic HTML tags with an

```
<img src="">.
```

I am trying to setText() for a TextView in my activity.

Any idea on how I can get the actual images in the TextView?

```
myString = "<img src = "http://...."> <p><b> Some Text<b></p>
```

Anyone can please point out a correct way to do this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865452/is-it-possible-to-display-inline-images-from-html-in-an-android-textview

Comment: Android's `Html` class supports limited HTML attributes. Check this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/3150456/2244476 to know what all attribute are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Display a strings which has HTML tags in a TextView usually a cumbersome process normally I do something like this.

**Show String Html into TextView**

- `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(your_string_html));`

**Listener to links from String HTML**

- `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

**Show images in a TextView** (It is the most laborious)

```
public class PicassoImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {

    final Resources resources;

    final Picasso picasso;

    final TextView textView;

    public PicassoImageGetter(final TextView textView, final Resources resources, final Picasso picasso) {
        this.textView  = textView;
        this.resources = resources;
        this.picasso     = picasso;
    }

    @Override public Drawable getDrawable(final String source) {
        final BitmapDrawablePlaceHolder result = new BitmapDrawablePlaceHolder();

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(final Void... meh) {
                try {
                    return picasso.load(source).get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap bitmap) {
                try {
                    final BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap);

                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

                    result.setDrawable(drawable);
                    result.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

                    textView.setText(textView.getText()); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }.execute((Void) null);

        return result;
    }

    static class BitmapDrawablePlaceHolder extends BitmapDrawable {

        protected Drawable drawable;

        @Override
        public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
            if (drawable != null) {
                drawable.draw(canvas);
            }
        }

        public void setDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
            this.drawable = drawable;
        }

    }
}
```

**You must use the class as follows:**

```
PicassoImageGetter picassoImageGetter = new PicassoImageGetter(txtView,getResources(), Picasso.with(this));

    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(your_string_html),picassoImageGetter,null);
```

Automatically you can show your images and text into TextView I hope it helps!

*Look this link if you never used Picasso o other library for download images.*
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en