# Read HTML file from Website and convert into App

Tags: android

I am looking into developing an App that will convert a website into more readable data for an android app. I am at university and have an online notice board which can be viewed on the web but if possible I would like to transfer this into an app on android to make it more easy to read on mobile devices.

What I thinking is that the app would go to the website where the notice board is held and read in the html code to display each notice in a list adapter view. Each notice is within its own div so I assume I could use that to split each notice up into its own button on the list adapter view. Is this possible and if so how I can go about doing this. I have tried google for an answer but I have not yet found a solution to this problem.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes it's possible. What are you having trouble with? What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android

Answer (score 3):

It seems overly complicated to me. I wouldn't handle all that using Android. I'd crawl the data on a machine (server) and then I'd convert all needed data to JSON and have the Android (client) fetch the data using a simple JSON parser.

In my opinion that would be the easiest solution if you don't have access to the server the website is hosted on to get it generate a JSON feed for you directly.

**EDIT:** In answer to your comment Boardy.

Here is the official website of the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) project in order to get an understanding of what it is. Then if you have access to the webserver providing that page (I assume it is a PHP based site) and want to modify or add the functionality of providing a JSON feed then you should also take a look at the [PHP JSON documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

To parse JSON on Android check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android) and also don't forget to take a look at the official Android documentation on their [JSON implementation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have any clues where I can find information on how to do this with JSON, it isn't something I have ever used or know much about.

Comment: Doing it in android is more overly complicated than having a server dedicated to just converting html to json?

Comment: @Falmarri parsing a HTML file in Android is that easy? Why don't you provide a good example then?