# Make android app out of website

Tags: android, json, web, jsoup

I want to make an Android App of a website.It's an online shopping type website. 
So how can I do that? How to retrieve data from website? And how can I use the database that was used in the website? Can anyone provide me some good tutorial link?

Comment: You need to have a middle-man per say.

Comment: This is far too general a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is view web pages from your app you can build a native android app and use WebViews (http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/). With WebViews you can display your web pages inside your app.  Or perhaps you don't want to display the actual page and want to obtain just the content. If so see the links below:

making a http call within your app:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506039/770061

other related discussion which may be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4167202/770061

I'm not quite sure what you mean by how you would use the database. The http request will eventually use the database based on what webpage you request.

Answer (score 1):

First in first,
the data between the phone and the server's database can be exchanged using [json](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http://www.json.org/&ei=2CNoUpyaJ8q-rgf__4HYBw&usg=AFQjCNEzAKsPX13LBmYrggE8ipoZ31-Uag&sig2=0nmdJbhVpFVJYj7A4a8Itw&bvm=bv.55123115,d.bmk) format .
For this you need to write scripting code that will release the data from the database in json format , and your android application can hit the json request to the database .
I prefer using PHP for scripting.

Once the data has been recieved you can use it to populate the lists/grids/view in your app directly or store it in SQLite database .

You can view one tutorial on [how to connect Android with PHP ,MYSQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

> All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try PhoneGap: a free app creator using HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript :)
http://phonegap.com

Answer (score -1):

hire someone on elance (very inexpensive) and he'll use phonegap if you want it for iOS and WP8 also.  Depending on the site, it should take the elance guy about 4 to 10 days.

if you have to do it yourself. then if you have any pages with a mix of server side code and html/javascript, you have to split them.  Do all the UI in javascript, and have it do ajax calls for the data.  However, this is not at all going to be easy.  I got downvoted for saying "hire somebody" instead of explaining, but you didn't give a lot of details, so it's fair to say you really don't know where to start.  In that case, if you need it done this month, you gotta hire someone.  If you're going to do it yourself, you're in for dozens of hours of research and testing.  You can come back here when you have a specific programming question you're stuck on.