# android HTML parsing

Tags: android, html, parsing

how to parse HTML tag using XML parsing

I am parsing XML file but from XML file i also want to parse HTML that contain

`<desc> <img>`

and similar tags... thanks in advance :):)

Comment: Maybe duplicate with [Parse HTML in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution i've used    .. etc tag
  ]]>
and it works fine for me

Comment: i got the solution i've used  <![CDATA[
   content that may contain <img> <h> <b>.. etc tag
  ]]>
and it works fine for me