# android HTML parsing

Tags: android, html, parsing, local

i have parsed my XML file that is locally stored,now i also want to parse HTML data from that same file

the portion of my XML file is like this

[image]

Comment: what does the file look like?

Comment: Why same [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416453/android-html-parsing) 3 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used CDATA and solved the problem :)