# creating a smartphone client for windows phone 7 or android

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, portal, software-design

I'm trying to design an android or windows phone 7 app (a client) that would fetch the news from a website, that website doesn't provide an api or xml files.

My question is, whats the best way to do that? Should I just download the html file and parse its content?
Am sorry if my questions is a little vague, but am not asking for code. I need some guidelines or approaches to do that.

Note: I wont violate any copyrights, am just creating a portal for my University website.

Comment: Tim's answer is most likely to be what you want if your University's website doesn't provide any 'formal' feed (such as RSS, for example). Be aware that it's basically 'web-scraping' which means reverse-engineering the HTML from the pages. This is fine (I do it myself) but is always a risk if the page format(s) get changed at some time in the future. Good luck.

Comment: android or WP7? It'll make a big difference to how you do this based on the platform you're building for.

Comment: @mistersquonk, thanks, your comment is helpful

Comment: @Matt , if you read my question, you would know am not asking about code. am just asking about the concept. anyway thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/faq before asking about concepts.

Comment: oh, i see now. so should i delete this question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Windows 7, there is a version of the HtmlAgility Pack for WP7.

Here is a bit of sample code:

```
public void Hap()
{
    HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("http://www.mycollege.edu/news", OnCallback);           
}

private void OnCallback(object s, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted htmlDocumentLoadCompleted)
{    
    var htmlDocument = htmlDocumentLoadCompleted.Document;
    //use agilitypack to parse out news    
}
```

Another approach is to have a service of some sort actually do the scraping and management of the news data then you control the format that the mobile devices consume like XML or JSON.

Comment: yea, i think theres no other way but to parse the html, thanks! I liked the service idea, so i can control the format in case the website changes

Comment: For .net the agility pack seems to be the best solution I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question for some clues on html parsing. [Parse HTML in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android)

***spoiler*** here is a link that has some java html parsing things that you can try: 
http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Depending on the html that you are trying to parse you may have better or worse luck actually getting the content you want to out of it.