# How to parse HTML Heading

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I have this HTML i am parsing.

```
<div id="articleHeader">
<h1 class="headline">Assassin's Creed Revelations: The Three Heroes</h1>
<h2 class="subheadline">Exclusive videos and art spanning three eras of assassins.</h2>
<h2 class="publish-date"><script>showUSloc=(checkLocale('uk')||checkLocale('au'));document.writeln(showUSloc ? '<strong>US, </strong>' : '');</script>

<span class="us_details">September 22, 2011</span>
```

What i want to do it parse the "headline" subheadline and publish date all to seperate Strings

Comment: Check out this previously asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the proper [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to grab them.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String headline = document.select("#articleHeader .headline").text();
String subheadline = document.select("#articleHeader .subheadline").text();
String us_details = document.select("#articleHeader .us_details").text();
// ...
```

Or a tad more efficient:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element articleHeader = document.select("#articleHeader").first();
String headline = articleHeader.select(".headline").text();
String subheadline = articleHeader.select(".subheadline").text();
String us_details = articleHeader.select(".us_details").text();
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Android has a [SAX parser built into it](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html) . You can use other standard XML parsers as well.

But I think if ur HTML is simple enough u could use RegEx to extract string.

Comment: Regex? *Shudder.* Did you miss the `jsoup` tag?

Comment: yup I did miss jsoup, and I like RegEx

Comment: I like regex too. But, to parse HTML? Totally the wrong tool.

Comment: Not to parse but to get some specific data from text. its simpler that way at time