# Parsing this page with Sax

Tags: android, android-listview, sax, saxparser

I am trying to parse a webpage, the values i want to parse are included in certain TD tags.
Can someone please help me to get along? I am getting a syntax error line1 column62.

Goal is to pass the values to a listview later on, so that it shows Nieuw beltegoed: € 2,50

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
<head>
<TABLE class=personaltable cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
 <TBODY>
  <TR class=alternativerow>
   <TD>Nieuw beltegoed:</TD>
   <TD>€ 2,50</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>Tegoed vorige periode:</TD>
   <TD>€ 3,62</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR class=alternativerow>
   <TD>Tegoed tot 09-11-2011:</TD>
   <TD>€ 1,12</TD>    
  </TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>
   <TD height=25></TD>
  <TR class=alternativerow>
   <TD>Verbruik sinds nieuw tegoed:</TD>
   <TD>€ 3,33</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>Ongebruikt tegoed:</TD>
   <TD>€ 1,79</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR class=alternativerow>
   <TD class=f-Orange>Verbruik boven bundel:</TD>
   <TD class=f-Orange>€ 0,00</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>Verbruik dat niet in de bundel zit*:</TD>
   <TD>€ 0,00</TD>
  </TR>
 </TBODY>
</TABLE>
</head>
```

My Saxhandler so far:

```
// ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private boolean in_TABLE = false;
    private boolean in_TBODY = false;
    private boolean in_TR = false;
    private boolean in_TD = false;

    private ParsedExampleDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    public ParsedExampleDataSet getParsedData() {
            return this.myParsedExampleDataSet;
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================
    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
            // Nothing to do
    }

    /** Gets be called on opening tags like: 
     * <tag> 
     * Can provide attribute(s), when xml was like:
     * <tag attribute="attributeValue">*/
    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                    String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("TABLE class=personaltable cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0")) {
                    this.in_TABLE = true;
            }else if (localName.equals("TBODY")) {
                    this.in_TBODY = true;
            }else if (localName.equals("TR class=alternativerow")) {
                    this.in_TR = true;
            }else if (localName.equals("TD")) {
                    // Extract an Attribute
                    String attrValue = atts.getValue("TD");
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(attrValue);
                    myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedInt(i);
            }
    }

    /** Gets be called on closing tags like: 
     * </tag> */
    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
                    throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("TABLE class=personaltable cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0")) {
                    this.in_TABLE = false;
            }else if (localName.equals("TBODY")) {
                    this.in_TBODY = false;
            }else if (localName.equals("TR class=alternativerow")) {
                    this.in_TR = false;
            }else if (localName.equals("TD")) {
                    // Nothing to do here
            }
    }

    /** Gets be called on the following structure: 
     * <tag>characters</tag> */
    @Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
            if(this.in_TD){
            myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}
```

Comment: The SAX parser is designed to parse XML, not HTML. Most HTML pages contain errors regarding their XML structure. For parsing HTML files you should better use a dedicated HTML parser.

Comment: Hi Robert, thx for answering.
I am going to use the JSoup parser, ithink it is the best way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to parse HTML page it is easier to use [dom](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) than SAX.

Also you can check this post it is answered [how to parse html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android)

Comment: Hi ahmed, ok thx for the answer.
I already saw the JSoup parser and i also have some code for it but i am strugling to get the 2 elements in a listview.
Can you help?

Comment: Submit another question that represent your situation (the jSoup issue) and provide enough code to help others help you

Comment: But DOM processing requires a lot of RAM. For larger pages this costs RAM and speed on Android.

Comment: it depend on the case and size of files.