# Allow Android SDK to search through website?

Tags: android, search, webview

Let's say there's website X. Website X has a search function that'll return articles/documents/whatever. Whatever it returns will include a link so the user could click on it to go to said article. All of this would be without an API. Would it be possible for an android application to query a search on a random website, get the results and display them in the app, without the user actually seeing the website?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course. All you want to do is write the app such that it performs the query to the website on behalf of the user; that way it gets the HTML response. When it gets the HTML page as a response, you parse that and reformat it into something more appropriate for the app.

Look at this SO question if you want more information on HTML parsers in Java: [Parse HTML in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android)