# How to make link "a href=" in TextView clickable without using .setText(Html.FromHtml)

Tags: java, android, html, xml, xml-parsing

i'm doing the rss reader and i need your help. I'm parsing an xml file and getting the next content of  tag

```
<p>
    <img class="alignright size-full wp-image-115203" alt="10 мероприятий, которые можно посетить в марте" src="http://ain.ua/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/secr2011-nov1-300x200.jpg" width="300" height="200" title="10 мероприятий, которые можно посетить в марте"
    />Предлагаем вашему вниманию небольшой список ИТ мероприятий марта, которые пройдут в Украине. В нашем
    <a href="http://ain.ua/events">календаре мероприятий</a>, вы можете найти еще больше мероприятий, которые мы рекомендуем вам к посещению.</p>
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="http://ain.ua/event/seminar-kpi-motivaciya-sistema-oplaty-po-rezultatu">Семинар “KPI-Мотивация. Система оплаты по результату”</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://ain.ua/2013/03/04/114970">Бесплатный семинар об организации системы внутренних коммуникаций и мотивации сотрудников</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://ain.ua/event/targetirovaniya-reklamnyx-kampanij-po-celevym-auditoriyam">Круглый стол «Возможности таргетирования рекламных кампаний по целевым аудиториям»</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://ain.ua/event/kak-zastavit-sajt-prodavat-bolshe">Бесплатный вебинар «Как заставить сайт продавать больше?»</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://ain.ua/event/6-j-seminar-effektivnyj-internet-marketing-dlya-biznesa">6-й семинар «Эффективный интернет-маркетинг для бизнеса»</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://ain.ua/event/internet-marketing-2013">Всеукраинский Форум «Дни Интернет-маркетинга» 2013</a>
    </li>
```

I need that all of these links where clickable and with name beetwen name_of_link

I have the next code, wich parsing needed xml-file

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML(resourceURL);
    Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, XMLfunctions.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, "Date: "+XMLfunctions.formatDate(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, KEY_DATE_TIME)));



        map.put(KEY_DESC, Html.fromHtml(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, KEY_DESC),null,null).toString());
        map.put(KEY_LINK, Html.fromHtml(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, KEY_LINK)).toString());
        mylist.add(map);            
    }       


    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                    new String[] { "title","pubDate", "description","link" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_pubdate, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item_link });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

My question is : how to parse and transform  data that in output i will get normal text with clickable links, like in this source http://feeds.feedburner.com/ainua?format=xml

I'm very sorry for wasting your time if this arcticle is already exist, but unfortunately, i don't know how to fing it. Any help is appreciated, because i've spend many hours trying to resolve this task, but i don't where i need to look for. Thx.

Comment: try `android:autoLink="all"` on your TextView inside your layout xml

Comment: this is the first thing that i've done without any profit

Answer (score 0):

I would try to implement my own Adapter-Class for the ListView and modify the views created for each row in the adapters corresponding method.

Comment: i'm understanding you idea, but...could you give me some link on example, because i donn't know how i need to modify my views. Thx a lot for idea.

Comment: i have found how to place link like "Some text <a href='google.com'>google</a> into ListActivity(i have override the getView() method in my own MyArrayAdapter class that extends extends ArrayAdapter) and....it's show me link exactly what i need!...But there is another problem. Those link is not clickable )) ...(((..Could you tell where i need to look for, to make this link clickable? The content (for example, "Some text, google.com") in ListActivity container is not clickable. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the HTML yourself if you don't want to use `HTML.fromHTML()`, while you can easily fetch the `href` links with RegEx, you still need to handle the image tags, lists, etc so RegEx is not the real answer. This question should help: [Parse HTML in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188049/1267661)

In case you decide to try parsing the HTML with RegEx, please read: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-co҉ntained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1267661). It explains why RegEx cannot do th̵is.

Comment: Thx for another one idea how to parse html, i'm really appreciated for it, i'll use it. But my main question is how to display a lot of links like this one <a href="http://google.com">google</a> in my own ListActivity class and make then clickable. Thx for your time.