# what is the faster way to get the first img from URL string?

Tags: java, string

It must recognize both forms:

```
<img src='http://www.mysite.com/myimg.png' width="89px" >
<img alt="ciao" width="89px" src="http://www.mysite.com/myimg.png" >
```

Comment: Please don't try to parse HTML.

Comment: Are you trying to actually get the image, or just the filename of the image?

Comment: I need only the filename. Thanks

Comment: You should look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android

Comment: We don't actually know that this is HTML - it could equally be XML or an entry in a `.properties` file. If this is the absolute total of text you have, and you known that those 2 quote variations are all you will have to deal with, then go ahead and use a regex: `^src=['"]([^'"]+)['"]$`

Comment: Use an HTML parser. It's 2013, FFS.

Comment: According to @Stewart we don't knw whether this html, or xml e.t.c. If is html just use JSoup libray and just do doc.select("img").first() or doc.select("img src").first().text().

Comment: @Immanuel.I.George thanks it works very well and it is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Please upvote my comment as the answer if it help u. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick code I made. Not tested but it should work. Basically we cut up the string into a array of sub strings with "/" being where we cut. So one of our sub strings has to contain the image, if not then there is no image file.

```
String[] src2=src.split("/");
String result="noting found !";

for(int i=0; i < src2.length; i++) {
   if( src2[i].contains("img") && (src2[i].contains(".png") || src2[i].contains(".jpg")/* more extensions */) ) { // add more extensions if needed
      result = src2[i];
      break;
   {
}

result = result.split(" ")[0]; //will cut at the first "space" and take only the "img.jpg" not the "width"

if(!result.equals("noting found !")) System.out.println("We found an image: "+result);
```

Comment: Did you mean src2.length ;)

Comment: without the (). Anyway this doesn't work well... It prints all the <img tag and all the info related such as width ecc...

Comment: Well the rest depends on the data you get. Before you edited your question, there where no img at the beginning nor any widths... just a little modification will be enough though. There fixed. ;)