# Android fetching images by URL

Tags: java, android, api

I am retrieving images from a server in my android application. I am trying to retrieve the last ten (10) images of a NOAA radar. The only information they give me is a directory link to start off with:

" To view and retrieve the 20 most recent radar images then the URL is...
  http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/FWS/ "

If you go there, you will notice that there are many URLs to the past images. Each URL has specific data to it pretaining to the radar you are fetching for.

But how in the heck do you fetch these images when you do not know of the times they were updated? The update times are jumpy all over the place...

The only documentation of this is found here and I have found no useful knowledge...
http://forecast.weather.gov/jetstream/doppler/ridge_download.htm

Thanks for all those that help! :-)

Comment: You have any code written to fetch images?

Comment: date and time is in image name so probably you can short them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the perfect solution but you can do it like this:
Solution 1:
Open the page http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/FWS/ and parse it with [html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android) to get all images names.
Solution 2:
Open the image [URL](http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/FWS/FWS_20140111_0421_N0R.gif) and change the "**date and time**" `N0R/FWS/FWS_YYYYMMDD_hhmm_N0R.gif` if you get **not found exception**, so there is no update
**Hope this helps you**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I think Ill give a try to soultion 2 :)