# Reading files from web directory with android

Tags: java, android, file, directory

I need to read all directory file links and I do this

```
File mfile=new File("http://192.168.1.86/web/ServerSideImages/Actualities/3/");
File[] list=mfile.listFiles();

System.out.println("list"+mfile.listFiles().length);
for(int i=0;i<mfile.listFiles().length;i++)
{
   System.out.println("hidden path files.."+list[i].getAbsolutePath()); 
}
```

but in logcat it says **java.lang.NullPointerException** where is my mistake please

Answer (score 1):

Here are your problems (mainly misunderstandings):

- `File`  does not work for files in the network
- Even if `File` worked for that, the list at the url is likely just a html list, so:

Here is what to do:

- Have a look at [HTTPClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) to get the html list at the url (Also make sure to do that in a background thread - `AsyncTask` will help)
- Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android) on how to parse an html