# Get JSON from a div in html

Tags: android, html, android-json

I have a hidden div which by JavaScript gets filled with json text. I need to find this div and read the json text from it. How can this be done?

```
<html>
    <div id="hiddenJSON"> 
        {
            "id":"1234",
            "Name":"Jonas",
            "Address":"Test Road 5",
            "Phone":"1234-1234-1234"
        }
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code :-

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("<div id=\"hiddenJSON\">") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("</div>"));
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

But better solution is you have to receive data without html tag so talk with back end person.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use a library for this such as `JSoup`. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android) about parsing html code

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i solved this:

`result` is the response from `@JavascriptInterface`

**WebView Fragment**

```
WebView wv = ...
wv.addJavascriptInterface( this, "android" );
wv.loadUrl( "javascript:android.showHTML(document.getElementById('hiddenJSON').innerHTML);" );
```

**Interface** in my **WebView Fragment**

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void showHTML( String result ) {

    // handle JSON (result)

}
```

**Problem:**
I had to get the result from my WebView in order to get the JavaScript to run (filling this hidden div with JSON).