# find specific string in html source by using RegEx

Tags: java, android, html, regex

It is simple.

I just want to extract some String values from unicode HTML source.

The original source looks like below:

```
<div id="encompass">
    <tr class="lineonoff">
                <td class="xsmall">27</td>
                <td>DATE</td>
                <td class="left">TITLE</td>
                <td>STATUS</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:viewData(ID, '')" class="button purple small"><span>A</span></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="lineonoff">
                <td class="xsmall">28</td>
                <td>DATE</td>
                <td class="left">TITLE</td>
                <td>STATUS</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:viewData(ID, '')" class="button purple small"><span>B</span></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="lineonoff">
                <td class="xsmall">29</td>
                <td>DATE</td>
                <td class="left">TITLE</td>
                <td>STATUS</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:viewData(ID, '')" class="button purple small"><span>C</span></a></td>
              </tr>
</div>
```

I want to extract TITLE, DATE,STATUS,ID.

I tried many possible variations of RegEx but failed at last..

```
 final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN_STRING);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result.toString());
```

How can I extract those values? Thank you!

Comment: ...and particularly [its legendary answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/115145). In short, don't use regular expressions. Parse the HTML with an HTML parser. A search on `java html parser` in a major search engine will turn up many options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you [should not use a regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1064270).
Prefer [use a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android).

But after all that considerations, something dirty like that, could make the job:

```
<tr[\s\S]*?class\="left">([^<]*)[\s\S]*?<td>([^<]*)[\s\S]*?viewData\(([^\(]*),
```

https://regex101.com/r/lZ6rE0/1