# Parse HTML in android for customise design

Tags: android, wordpress

Currently working on android application in which I have to fetch posts from word-press blog to show articles. When I fetch contents for a particular post it provides data in form of html.
How to parse the html to get data from it and customise it according to my design.Or any best library I can use for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse HTML in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android)

Comment: try using `Html.fromHtml(/*content*/)`. Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html for more reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse HTML in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android)