# I want to extract image URL and Text from the HTML String. Below is what my requirement is

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

```
<img src="http://bvcelearningadmin.in/assets/upload_data/test_data/test/taketestimg.png" alt="" width="109" height="100" />What this is representing about?"
```

I have tried in this way. But I am able get only the Text and the Image URL is unable to extract.

```
String dislayvalureareprint = "<img src=\\\"http:\\/\\/bvcelearningadmin.in\\/assets\\/upload_data\\/test_data\\/test\\/taketestimg.png\\\" alt=\\\"\\\" width=\\\"109\\\" height=\\\"100\\\" \\/>My name is what tell me?\"";

Uri value = Uri.parse(dislayvalureareprint);

Log.d("displayurl","--- "+value);

Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(dislayvalureareprint);

Log.d("displaytext","--- "+spanned);
```

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: Hardcodeed OMG !!

Comment: check parsing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android

Comment: @JaydeepPatel thank you sir,i will try let you know.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel  but image url i'm not able to extract.

Comment: your string is not a valid `Uri`. It won't let you parse. To understand how to `extract image url from html`, please google it.

Answer (score 1):

This would do for you.

For image url

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src");
```

For the text part

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("img").html();
```

Remember this solution is based on the fact that there's only one img tag in the whole html. As you haven't shared the whole HTML, this is the best I can do and your selectors might change depending on your HTML code.