# How to get a specific text from a web page Android Studio

Tags: android

How to get a specific text from a web page Android Studio?

[image: How to get a specific text from a web page Android Studio]

Comment: First and foremost, welcome to SO, but this is not the way to ask a question. Consider reading How to ask questions here. Coming to your solution, use a library called JSoup to parse a html data. All the best.

Comment: what exactly is a problem for you to get it? what stops you from doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse HTML in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to find "HOW THAT WEBPAGE IS GETTING THAT DATA?",

1-If it is hard coded you can hardcode it in your android application.

2-If it is coming from any web service you need to parse JSON data into you application.

That's how you get the specific data from any web page.