# How to parse html string into string

Tags: android

I trying to parse this html string into String format, how can i do it?

```
<div class=\"timewrap nooffset\"><a href=\"https://ticketsbox.com/checkout/33352/\" onclick=\"ga('send','event','Время сеанса','imax','Абсолютно новые приключения Аладдина');newbrand(1006);tag_buy();\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"activeEvent\" rel=\"nofollow\">17:30</a></div>
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far? even search the google with same title? if so you can easily find https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409895/8809599

Answer (score 1):

You can use method from:

> [android.text.Html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
Html.fromHtml(String source, int flags);
```

Use it like that: `Html.fromHtml(str, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);`

returns a Spanned that may be converted to String with `toString()` method or set to textView as it is. `textView.setText(CharSequence);`