# how to get text message from html whatappurl in webview android

Tags: android

I am using a web view in an android app. I want to replace `content_from_whatsapp_url` to my a tag `MY-MESSAGE`. Could you help me please?

HTML:

```html
<a class="btn_whatsapp btn_prop_whatsapp"  href="whatsapp://send?text=MY-MESSAGE" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share</a>
```

Adroid:

```java
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content_from_whatsapp_url);

Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content_from_whatsapp_url);
startActivity(whatsappIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [JSoup](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-html-parser-using-jsoup-tutorial/).

Like this [Parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android):

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

//http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url
//Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```