# Getting JSON html data

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am getting JSON data from a word press database to add them to a mobile app using android studio. However, am facing many problems.
First, I need to keep the post content correctly viewed, but what about the html tags ?
After searching I added  JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT  | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to my output, but that didn't solve my problem. =

PHP CODE

```
<?php 
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    /*
    * Created by Belal Khan
    * website: www.simplifiedcoding.net 
    * Retrieve Data From MySQL Database in Android
    */
    
    //database constants
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', '');
    define('DB_PASS', '');
    define('DB_NAME', '');
    
    //connecting to database and getting the connection object
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    
    //Checking if any error occured while connecting
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }
    
    
    function getAttachment($post_title) {
        
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT guid,post_title  FROM wp_posts  WHERE `post_type`='attachment'  AND `post_title` = ?");
    $conn -> set_charset("utf8");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$post_title);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();    
    $stmt->bind_result($guid, $post_title); 
    $products_attach = array(); 
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $temp = array();
        $temp['guid'] = $guid; 
    

        array_push($products_attach, $temp);
    }
 return     $temp['guid'];
}
}

 

    
        
        
    
    
    //creating a query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, post_title, post_content  FROM wp_posts  WHERE `post_type`='lsvr_document'AND `post_status`= 'publish';");
    $conn -> set_charset("utf8");

    //executing the query 
    $stmt->execute();
    
    //binding results to the query 
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $content);
    
    $products = array(); 
    
    //traversing through all the result 
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $temp = array();
        $temp['id'] = $id; 
        $temp['title'] = $title; 
        $temp['link'] = getAttachment($temp['title']);
        $temp['content'] = $content; 
 
        array_push($products, $temp);
    }
    
    //displaying the result in json format 
//  echo json_encode($products, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE  | JSON_HEX_TAG );


 $json = json_encode($products, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT  | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

echo $json;
//print_r($products);

    
?>
```

Some of the Output

```
       "id": 867,
    "title": "إفادة إنجاز بناء مخالف",
    "link": "http:\/\/syncsecser.com\/municipal\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/09\/إفادة-إنجاز-بناء-مخالف.pdf",
    "content": "\u003C!-- wp:heading --\u003E\n\u003Ch2\u003Eالمستندات المرفقة و أماكن إنجازها\u003C\/h2\u003E\n\u003C!-- \/wp:heading --\u003E\n\n\u003C!-- wp:paragraph --\u003E\n\u003Cp\u003E1. طلب موقع من صاحب العلاقة أو من ينوب عنه قانوناً.\u003Cbr\u003E2. إفادة عقارية\u0026nbsp;شاملة.\u003Cbr\u003E3. أي مستند يثبت تاريخ إنجاز المخالفة.\u003C\/p\u003E\n\u003C!-- \/wp:paragraph --\u003E\n\n\u003C!-- wp:table {\u0022className\u0022:\u0022is-style-regular\u0022} --\u003E\n\u003Cfigure id=\u0022table1\u0022 class=\u0022wp-block-table is-style-regular\u0022\u003E\u003Ctable\u003E\u003Ctbody\u003E\u003Ctr\u003E\u003Ctd\u003E\u003Cbr\u003E\u003Cbr\u003E-\u003Cstrong\u003E\u003Cu\u003Eمدّة\u0026nbsp;الإنجاز :\u003C\/u\u003E\u003C\/strong\u003E\u003Cbr\u003E\u0026nbsp;ثلاثة أيام سنداً\u0026nbsp;لتعميم وزير الداخلية والشؤون البلدية والقروية رقم 8\/99.\u003Cbr\u003E\u003Cbr\u003E-\u003Cstrong\u003E\u0026nbsp;الرسوم\u0026nbsp;المتوجبة\u003Cbr\u003E\u003Cbr\u003E\u0026nbsp;\u003C\/strong\u003E\u003Cbr\u003E1.\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;رسم الإفادة الفنية:\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp; 2000 ل.ل.\u003Cbr\u003E\u0026nbsp;\u003Cbr\u003E2.\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;رسم طابع مالي:\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;\u0026nbsp;1000 ل.ل.\u003Cbr\u003E\u003C\/td\u003E\u003C\/tr\u003E\u003C\/tbody\u003E\u003C\/table\u003E\u003C\/figure\u003E\n\u003C!-- \/wp:table --\u003E"
},
```

Comment: Please describe your main problem in one sentence. Define 'correctly'. What is the problem with HTML tags?

Comment: Yes the html tags , but I want to keep the content divided in to list and h1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is you can encode your content to base64 and then in your mobile app or any other page you want to parse the content, you can just simply decode this base64.

Comment: How to parse the content ?

Comment: in PHP, you can use `base64_decode($str)` on the base64 encoded content.

Comment: yes this is in the php api , but how to parse it on the other side from the mobile app

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android) @cccwsb